# On the definition/notation for pseudoholomorphic curves

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, symplectic-geometry

A pseudoholomorphic curve is a map $u:(\Sigma,j) \to (M,J)$ from a Riemann surface $\Sigma$ with an almost complex structure $j$ to a manifold $M$ with an almost complex structure $J.$ We require moreover that $u$ satisfies the "Cauchy-Riemann equations"

$$ J \circ du = du \circ j. \qquad (*)$$

I assume that this is to be understood as an equality of maps $T_p\Sigma \to T_{u(p)}M$ for every $p \in \Sigma$ (or even as a bundle homomorphism). However, choosing local $j$-holomorphic coordinates $(s,t)$ on $\Sigma$, so that $j(\partial_s) = \partial_t,$ many authors state that the equation above is equivalent to

$$ \partial_s(u) + J(u)\partial_t(u) = 0.$$

I don't understand this statement. In fact, I don't even understand what the symbols above are supposed to represent. What is $J(u)?$ I understand that, taking (for simplicity) $M = \mathbb{C}^n$ with its standard complex structure, the equation $(*)$ above reduces to a system of $2n$ equations, corresponding to the usual Cauchy-Riemann equations. But then $J$ simply corresponds to a matrix, and doesn't depend in any way on $u.$ Why would one write $J(u),$ then?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$J$ is regarded as a section of the bundle of endomorphisms of $TM$, i.e. as a map $M\to\text{End}(TM$).

Rewrite the equation as $du+J\circ du\circ j=0$, and now write $du$ locally in terms of $ds$ and $dt$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Things I don't understand:

(1) I understand that $J$ is such a section. How does this help us make sense out of the expression $J(u)?$

(2) Let me see if I can expand on your second comment. Locally, $u$ can be viewed as a $2n$-tuple, $u = (u_1,\ldots,u_{2n})$ of real-valued functions of two real variables $s,t.$ For each of these, we have $du_i = \partial_s(u_i) ds + \partial_t(u_i) dt.$ I suppose we can write this more compactly as $du=\partial_s(u) ds + \partial_t(u) dt.$ Anyway, applying your equation to $\partial_s$ gives us $\partial_s(u) + J(\partial_t(u))= 0.$

Comment: $J(u)$ is composition, i.e. for any $z\in \Sigma$ we get a map $T_{u(z)}M\to T_{u(z)}M$.

Answer (score 2):

What Chris said is correct and completely to the point, but would have been too abstract for me when I was first learning. Apologies if his answer sufficed.

Consider the case of $M = \mathbb{C}^n$. For each point $z \in \mathbb{C}^n$, $T_zM$ can be identified with $\mathbb{C}^n$. An almost complex structure gives you a complex structure on *each* tangent space. This means that we should see it (in this case) as a $\mathbb{C}^n$ parametric family of matrices $J(z)$, where each $J(z)$ should be thought of as an endomorphism of $T_zM$. (In this case, the global trivialization of $T_zM$ is what allows us to identify this with a matrix.)

Now, consider a map $u \colon D \to M$. $J \circ du$ is then, very explicitly, given by $J(u(z)) du(z)$, where we now think of $du(z)$ as the Jacobian matrix of partial derivatives of $u$.

Everything now follows as Chris and you observe.

Comment: Thanks for the more in-depth reply, Sam. I understand everything in your first paragraph. It's the second part that really confuses me. Would you mind to detail it some more, perhaps also mentioning the various identifications you're making? I'm just trying to understand what's really going on between the notation.

Comment: A key point: $M$ is *not* a complex manifold. This means that the coordinate chart we choose is just a real coordinate chart. Thus, we should think of $z = (x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, \dots, x_n, y_n)$. At each point in this coordinate chart, the tangent space is spanned by $\partial_{x_i}, \partial_{y_i}$. This gives a trivialization of the tangent space over each point in our coordinate chart. Now, finally, $J(x_1, y_1, \dots, x_n, y_n)$ is a matrix that tells you what $J$ does to the local vector fields $\partial_{x_i}$, $\partial_{y_i}$.

Comment: Now, consider $u \colon D \to M$. Look at some point $z \in D$, and let $p = u(z) \in M$. Then, we take a coordinate chart around $p$ as in my previous comment. We can then think of $u \colon D \to \mathbb{R}^{2n}$. The differential $du \colon T_z D \to T_{u(z)} \mathbb{R}^{2n}$. Now, $J$ is an endomorphism of $T_{u(z)}\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, and this matrix is then $J( u(z ))$. Does this make sense?